# How to extend Rails Mountable Engine Assets in Application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

Imagine we have Rails Engine `blog`.

The engine's structure is:

```
blog
    assets
    javascripts
        blog
            master.js
            application.js
    controllers
        ...
    helpers
        ...
```

`application.js` is

```
//= require_tree .
```

`master.js` holds some JavaScript code.

Also I have my application using this engine at `/blog`.

My question is: How can I add some JavaScript code to engine from my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is:

1. Ensure bundle files (application.js, application.css) on plugin and application have different names. In my example plugin's bundle will be bundle.js, and application's bundle — application.js
2. bundle.js will look like:

   require_tree .
3. application.js will look like:

   require blog/bundle

   require_tree .

The problem was in name overlapping - application's bundle was overlapping engines one.